# Laravel routes prefix and ressources resulting in 404 not found

Tags: laravel

I've this Laravel routing issue. I don't really understand why my route:list tells me that an `{}` empty is appended to the URL? I believe this is the reason why my calls returns 404 not found.

I'd like `DepartmentController` to be inside my grouped body as I need the ID for other purposes. If I move `ressource` outside the prefix/group this scenarie works, but the other dosen't. This is my preferred way of structuring my routes, but it troubles me that `/` dosen't just use the prefixed URL, but it for some reason append it with `{}`

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Calling URL:** `/department/1/edit`

**Result:** `404 Not Found`

**Routes:**

```
Route::prefix( 'department/{department_id?}' )->group( function () {
     Route::resource( '/', 'DepartmentController' );
}
```

**`php artisan route:list`:**

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | department/{department_id?}/{}                                           | show                              | App\Http\Controllers\DepartmentController@show                            | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | department/{department_id?}/{}                                           | update                            | App\Http\Controllers\DepartmentController@update                          | web          |
|        | DELETE    | department/{department_id?}/{}                                           | destroy                           | App\Http\Controllers\DepartmentController@destroy                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | department/{department_id?}/{}/edit                                      | edit                              | App\Http\Controllers\DepartmentController@edit                            | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | department/{department_id?}/create                                       | create                            | App\Http\Controllers\DepartmentController@create                          | web          |
|        | POST      | department/{department_id?}                                              | store                             | App\Http\Controllers\DepartmentController@store                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | department/{department_id?}                                              | index                             | App\Http\Controllers\DepartmentController@index                           | web          |
```

**Update:**
If I make a custom route like this:

```
Route::get( 'customedit', 'DepartmentController@editasddas' );
```

and request the url: `/department/1/editasddas`. It works as it's suppose to, but there is actually a reason why I'm using the ressource: to keep the routes as clean as possible. The ressource-routes have been implemented for that reason aswell, and I just need to implement the basic CRUD operations. Is this a bug in Laravel, or is this basically not possible? - really strange I think. It's not that complex.

Comment: Did you try with `department/{department_id}` for your prefix?

Comment: Yes. Results in the same when I route:list

Comment: Not linked to your issue, but there is no `create` nor `store` route. Is that wanted?

Comment: Is this the first time you tried to put resource routes in your list with that way? I think that's because how `Route::resource` creates subroutes itself (automatically adding a resource parameter within URLs, the parameter being `{}` at the end).

Comment: try with `Route::resource( 'department/{department_id?}', 'DepartmentController' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have this issue because how `Route::resource` creates subroutes itself (automatically adding a resource parameter within URLs, the parameter being `{}` at the end).

Also, note you are currently generating a `index` route with a department parameter, and that's not really useful.

Best solution for me is to move out your parameter:

```php
Route::prefix( 'department' )->group( function () {
    Route::resource( '/', 'DepartmentController' );
});
```

In the other hand, the `department_id` parameter will not be facultative. And you will need to add the parameter within each other custom routes (but that's what `Route::resource` does with its own routes after all).

---

Second one is to keep your prefix and declare each route individually. But you will need to change the default route names because `department.index` and `department.show` will have the exact same methods (`GET` and `HEAD`) and URLs (`department/{department_id}`).

```php
Route::prefix('department/{department_id}')->group(function() {
    Route::match(['get', 'head'], '/', 'DepartmentController@index')->name('department.index');
    Route::match(['get', 'head'], '/show', 'DepartmentController@show')->name('department.show');

   /* Declare all the others. */
});
```

Comment: This actually works. However wasn't really the answer I was looking for. I really hoped that the ressource implementation could satisfy my needs, but it seems like I've to declare everything explicitly to create these basic endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

The `Route::resource` method alone will achieve what you're looking for:

```
Route::resource( 'department', 'DepartmentController' );
```

Check the docs on this here, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers